# Formato DATETIME SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de mudar o formato DateTime no SQL Server

EX: **2019-07-09 11:42:00** para **09-07-2019 11:42:00**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta é a forma de exibir a data, o banco de dados só retorna a data, como apresentá-la é feito depois.

Você pode formatar as datas de algumas maneiras diferentes no `sql-server`:

- Usando [`CAST e CONVERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): formatam não só datas, mas outros tipos também.
  Pode usar um formato direto, por exemplo:
  `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss')` ou pode ser usado um formato já definido (veja a tabela no link), por exemplo:
  `SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 105)`, que vai converter a data para string (varchar)  com o estilo de formatação 105.
- Usando [`SET DATEFORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): define um formato de data para a sessão de comandos atual, ou seja, uma sequência de comandos SELECT, uma STORED PROCEDURE, etc

Comment: Note que este não é o formato como a data está armazenada, é apenas o formato de exibição padrão.

Comment: sim vdd ficou mal escrito vou corrigir :)

Answer (score 4):

Datas não possuem formatos, datas são datas, tem um ponto na linha do tempo, só isso, formatos podem ser aplicados em textos que são as representações visuais para humanos lerem de datas (o mesmo vale para números). Então no momento que for imprimir alguma data você pode escolher o formato que deseja. Uma forma pode ser assim:

```
SELECT FORMAT(data, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/FormatDate.sql).

Answer (score 1):

EXEMPLO1 - Formato direto, importante que o mês tem que estar com M maiusculo, por que o resultado pode aparecer o minutos ao invés do mês

EXEMPLO2 - Exibe no formato que você precisa, porém o resultado é uma `string`, podendo ser convertida logo após para um `datetime` (EXEMPLO3). Ai fica da sua escolha.

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') AS EXEMPLO1
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),105) + SPACE(1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),108) AS EXEMPLO2
     , CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),105) + SPACE(1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),108)) AS EXEMPLO3
     , GETDATE() AS ORIGINAL
```